# send PIL.Image to django server side and get it back

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I don't know what's under the hood of sending an image from client side to server side, so stuck by the following scenario.

I want to send a `PIL.Image` object to django server side  using the [Python requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)  and get it back in order to use the `PIL.Image` object on server side.
As I have tested , if sent the `PIL.Image` object without any conversion , that is

```
r = requests.post(SERVER_URL,
                data={
                    'image': PILimage,#PILimage is of type PIL.Image
                    'wordPos':(86,23)
                    },
                )
```

then I just got a `str` object with value  `<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=149x49 at 0x13F25D0>` on server side, I guess it was caused by  `requests`, which converted the `PIL.Image` object to  a `str` object before sending, so **why  `requests`do the conversion ? why cannot we send the `PIL.Image` object without any conversion over the Internet ? please give some explanation here, thanks!**

Someone told me I could convert the `PIL.Image` object to `bytes` form then do the sending  , that is

```
r = requests.post(SERVER_URL,
                data={
                    'image': PILimage.tobytes(),#PILimage is of type PIL.Image
                    'wordPos':(86,23)
                    },
                )
```

but then  **how to get the image back to `PIL.Image` object on server side?** It seems [PIL.Image.frombytes()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes) won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Anything going over a wire must be a sequence of bytes, along with the way to interpret these bytes (if the protocol doesn't enforce some specific meaning).  In HTTP parlance, this means you have to add a Content-Type header declaring the interpretation of the bytes you send.

You can:

```
>>> import io
>>> file_like_object = io.BytesIO()
>>> PILImage.save(file_like_object, format='png')
```

Then your POST request should have a header `Content-Type: image/png` and send `file_like_object.getvalue()` as the body of the request.

Comment: why "Anything going over a wire must be a sequence of bytes"? I'd like a further explanation , I don't know much about computer networks

Comment: This is a very fundamental issue that I can't elaborate here. I advise you start from the [Wikipedia article for serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and keep on reading…

Comment: Thanks, I solved it finally https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453785/1485853

Answer (score 0):

For sending images

```
def myOCR(PILimage, wordPos):
  image = io.BytesIO()
  PILimage.save(image, 'png')  # 没有什么类型，这里就任意指定个吧；For images created by the library itself (via a factory function, or by running a method on an existing image), this attribute is set to None.
  image.seek(0)  # 要回到开始才行，不然后面requests读的时候会从结尾读，读不到数据

  r = requests.post(SERVER_URL,
      files={'image': image},
      data={'wordPos': wordPos}
  )

  result = r.json()
  return result['word']
```

In the Django side one could get the image using `Image.open(request.FILES['image'])`